# The $L^p(\mathbb R)$ norm is increasing as a function of $p$ (Update: It's false!)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Update: This is false. See the answers for a counterexample.

> Let $C\ge 1$ be a constant. Fix $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $p\ge C$. Show that $$p\rightarrow \left( \int |f|^p
>  \right)^{1/p}$$ is non-decreasing.

Comments: I'm posting this because there is (surprisingly) no good reference for this fact on the internet. If I recall correctly, differentiating with respect to $p$ will do the trick.

For the same problem on a finite measure space, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156977/another-property-of-the-function-phi-p-mapsto-int-fp-d-mu).

Comment: The spaces $L^p(\mathbb R)$ are not contained in each other for different $p\geq 1$. Maybe you should take $f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but this is true on a probability space and the proof is a straightforward application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @Potato You can indeed use the result on $L^p[-n,n]$ and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Potato I am not 100% sure about this but if you consider the functions $g_n = \lvert f \rvert 1_{[-n,n]}$ and apply monotone convergence then I think it would work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true: Consider the function $f(x)=\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)}(x)|x|^{-1/2}$. Then for $p\leq 2$ we have $\| f\|_{p}=\infty$ and for $p>2$ we get 
$$
\| f\|_p = \left(\frac{4}{p-2}\right)^{1/p}.
$$

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to know the error in the proof sketched in the comments (and given below by me in the answers)?

Comment: @Potato: Holder's inequality gives that $\| f\| _p \leq |X|^{1/p-1/q}\| f\|_q$ for any $p<q$, where the norms are taken over $X$. This means that when you let $n\to \infty$ (in this case $X=[-n,n]$ and so $|X|=2n$) in your argument you ruin the inequality.

Comment: I'm getting $||f||_p$ = $(\frac {4}{p+2})^{\frac 1p}$ which is increasing for p larger than 7.

Comment: @Ragnar Double check your work. (If you examine the integrand, you see it must diverge for $p=2$ because it looks like $1/x$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.)

Comment: $||f||_p$ = $(\int_{-1}^{1} |x|^{\frac {p}{2}})^{\frac 1p}$ = $2\int_0^1|x|^{\frac {p}{2}}) ^ {\frac 1p}$ = $(2[\frac {x^{\frac p2 +1}}{\frac p2 +1}]_0^1) ^ {\frac 1p}$ = $(4*[\frac {x^{\frac p2 +1}}{p+2}]_0^1)^ {\frac 1p}$ = $(\frac {4}{p+2})^ {\frac 1p}$

Comment: @Ragnar The integral is over the entire real line, excluding $(-1,1)$. Not $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Oh, I have awful eyes, you are correct it would diverge in that case. And, good point on differentiability above.

Comment: @Ragnar Indeed, this is a surprisingly subtle question. I was under the impression the norms were increasing!

Answer (score 0):

Jensen:

take q>p, examine:

$L(q,p)$ = $\frac {(\int |f|^q)^{\frac 1q}}{(\int |f|^p)^{\frac 1p}}$

By Jensen's inequality $(\int |f|^p)^{\frac qp}$ ≤ $(\int |f|^q)$ Because $\frac qp$≥1 $\Rightarrow$ $g(x)$ = $x^{\frac qp}$ is convex

Thus, $L(q,p)^q$≥ $\frac {\int |f|^q}{\int |f|^q}$ = 1 $\Rightarrow$ $L(q,p)$≥1 $\Rightarrow$ $p \rightarrow  (\int |f|^p)^{\frac 1p}$ is non decreasing

Comment: Some subtlety is needed here. Jensen's inequality cannot be applied directly on $L^p(\mathbb R)$ because it is not a probability space.

Comment: Missed that, anyway, the $L_p$ norm is a convex operator. Hence, if q>p, q(f)≥p(f)

Comment: Convex functions are not necessarily increasing. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Take derivative of L(p) = $(\int |f|^p)^{\frac 1p}$ wrt p. It's positive.

Comment: You can't differentiate under the integral sign unless you know the resulting integral converges (is dominated by an integrable function). Also the statement is false. See Jose27's answer.

Comment: if f $\in$ $L^p(\Bbb R)$ then the integral converges. At least that's what my functional analysis book says. If the integral is infinite, it does not converge and the function cannot be in $L^p(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: I mean the integral you obtain after differentiating with respect to $p$.